# How can I enter the '€' (Euro symbol) in the TTY?

Tags: command-line, tty, unicode-entry

I'm currently stuck in a login-screen loop after I installed Ubuntu Mate environment.

I know a solution to fix it but get stuck in TTY because I can't enter a `€` symbol. How can I enter one into the TTY?

Comment: What is your keyboard layout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just enter the `€` symbol in the same way into the TTY depending on your keyboard layout as you would do in a GUI.

The TTY is not capable of displaying non-ASCII characters, so it prints a `∎`-like symbol instead. The character is properly recognized though.

---

I tried this out by running the following command in a TTY:

```
echo "€" > eurotest.txt
```

Although the `€` was displayed as `∎` in the TTY, the file contained the correct Euro symbol when opening it through the GUI.

Comment: it displayed something like "Añ"... In the end I changed password in recovery mode and got it working but thank you anyway. :)

Comment: In my case on Ubuntu 16.06 € looks fine always, and I can always type it with AltGr+e.